# ios:I got a old project,when I login,there comes a issue

Tags: ios

The error is:

```
ERROR:Error Domain=isNOTValidJSONObject Code=0 "xxx" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=xxx}
```

I have motified the `App Transport Security Security Setting -> Allow Arbitrary Loads == YES`

Does this issue somebody meet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isNOTValidJSONObject`- so somewhere in code this is added to the created `NSError`. Probably the response from server is wrong and it can't be parsed as JSON response.